# image analysis (opencv or scikit image), deskewing of noisy scan

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

I do have some old bank statements as scan and would like to use google´s thesseract engine to extract the text. Works pretty well unless the image is slightly rotated. I thought of detecting the dashed lines in order to estimate the slope and afterwards the angle of rotation. However, it is tricky to get the parameters right.

If I could get rid of the large line artefact, I might use the minimum rotated bounding box (`cv2.minAreaRect`) on the text characters.

Maybe another strategy is suited better ? Any ideas ?

An example image (deleted some characters for data protection):

[image]

EIDT: I have found a solution which seems to work. However, I am stil wondering if there might be a faster solution (takes about 1.5 seconds per Image)

I do use [template matching](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_template.html) from skimage with following template:

[image]

```
template = plt.imread('template_long.png')
template = rgb2gray(template)
template = template > threshold_mean(template)

for i in range(1):
    # read in image
    img = cv2.imread('conversion/umsatz_{}.png'.format(i))
    # convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)

    # threshold the image, setting all foreground pixels to
    # 255 and all background pixels to 0
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1] 

    # edge detection
    #edges = cv2.Canny(thresh,2,100, apertureSize = 3)

    # fill the holes from detected edges
    #kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
    #dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)

    result = match_template(thresh, template)

    mask = result < 0.5
    r = result.copy()
    r[mask] = 0
    r[~mask] = 1
    plt.imshow(r)
```

Comment: If the problem is the big line, maybe you can filter it by size. if you manage to get the dashed lines correctly, then you can get a homography which maps the rotated rect of the rectangle between the dashed lines to a rectangle not rotated of the size you like. Then this homography can be used in the whole image to rectify it

Comment: I tried two other approaches which didn't work, but thought it could save you some time *not* to try those.  1) Defining a cost function that summed the image across rows, and then counting the number of zeros.  Optimizing that cost function would give you an image where lines are well separated.  2) Do the Hough transform, find the best matched line, and rotate by its angle.  (1) didn't work because the cost function is not smooth enough (2) Didn't work, because there is an artefact line that is much more prominent than the characters themselves.

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt instead of finding the *best* matched line which would be the artifact line, perhaps a better method would be to use all the other horizontal lines and average their slopes. You should be able to get a ton of lines from the text, especially with dilation.

Comment: @Moritz a less computationally expensive approach would be to resize both the image and template, should be able to give you similar results but with far less computation. An image with half the height and width would be four times faster computation.